# Subscribe to Jira search filter using jira Rest API

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I have created a Jira search filter, using this request:

```
POST /rest/api/2/filter
```

This worked pretty well. Now after I created the filter, I want to get automatically subscribed to it.

Is there a way to do it with the REST API? Or is the only possible way to do this manually?

I already found this in the documentation: https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.4.1/#api/2/filter-createFilter

There, I found the "subscriptions" property, but I can't seem to figure out how exactly I have to write this, to get the correct syntax.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a JIRA Feature Request that is still being considered for this to be implemented. Please take a look at [this](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRACLOUD-69318) for more details.

For now, all we can do is Fetch or Create Filters using the JIRA ReST APIs but editing the subscriptions should be manual tasks.

Please take a look at the following [Atlassian Question](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Subscribe-to-Jira-Filter-using-Rest-Api/qaq-p/1000170) which confirms the same.

***Details as provided in this Question:***

> You can do a GET to see the filter subscriptions values you have via:
>
> **GET /rest/api/2/filter/favourite?expand=subscriptions**

Hope this helps!